# Create an aggregation query of a table linked to another 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables, the first one stores information about a user, such as an email address, etc, and it updates dynamically (when a new user has registered). The second one stores the user's roles and it is a static table comes from the init SQL script. And the last one, named `user_status`, keeps track of changing a particular user's role by adding a new entry with the current timestamp.

Need to gather the current status (the latest created status entries) of all users grouped by `role` pointed to a number, which is a count of corresponding users.

```
/* table user_account stores top user information */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_account (
             id serial PRIMARY KEY,
             email text NOT NULL
);

/* table user_role keeps user's role ids */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_role (
             id serial PRIMARY KEY,
             role text NOT NULL
);

/* table user_status track a user role on change */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_status (
             id serial PRIMARY KEY,
             user_account_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES user_account(id),
             user_role_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES user_role(id),
             created timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT clock_timestamp()
);

INSERT INTO user_account(email) VALUES
( 'user1@myorg.com' ),
( 'user2@myorg.com' ),
( 'user3@myorg.com' );

INSERT INTO user_role (role) VALUES
( 'activation_required' ),
( 'regular' ),
( 'forum_only' ),
( 'moderator' ),
( 'admin' );

INSERT INTO user_status (user_account_id, user_role_id) VALUES
(1, 1), -- now user `user1@myorg.com` has `activation_required` role
(1, 5), -- now user `user1@myorg.com` has `admin` role
(2, 1), -- now user `user2@myorg.com` has `activation_required` role
(2, 2), -- now user `user2@myorg.com` has `regular` role
(3, 1), -- now user `user3@myorg.com` has `activation_required` role
(1, 4), -- now user `user1@myorg.com` has `moderator` role
(3, 2); -- now user `user2@myorg.com` has `regular` role
```

So after the latter insert query I expect to see

```
moderator | 1
regular   | 2
```

Because there is only 3 users (1+2), and at the current moment is one moderator and two regular users.

Comment: Please add more detail about your output...

Comment: @MDanish I've updated the description

Comment: Thanks for updates. Please explain about you output requirement. why/by which logic you required (data_b_1: 1, data_b_2: 2)

Answer (score 0):

So I've contrived a query that solves the issue:

```
SELECT user_role.role, COUNT(user_status.*)
FROM user_account, user_status
        JOIN user_role ON user_role.id = user_status.user_role_id
WHERE user_status.created = (SELECT MAX(created) FROM user_status WHERE user_account.id = user_status.user_account_id)
GROUP BY user_role.role
ORDER BY user_role.role;
```